# PostgreSQL query always return true

Tags: java, postgresql

I have query which must return a boolean but I always get the same result. I have tried this:

```
 boolean exist=stmt.execute("select exists(select 1 from calcul where 
 to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')=to_char("+dates+", 'YYYY-MM') AND
 idproduit="+codeP+" AND ppa="+PPA+" AND tr="+TR+" AND net="+NET+" AND 
 dateper='"+datePer+"')");
```

The result is always `true`, never `false`; why?

Comment: the `=` sign is the assignment sign, while `==` is a comparison sign.

Comment: Please use a `PreparedStatement`, do not concatenate SQL queries like that. You also need to use `executeQuery()` as clearly documented in the JavaDocs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [JavaDocs for `Statement#execute(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String))

> Returns:
>  `true` if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` if it
>   is an update count or there are no results

You could use [`Statement#executeQuery(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) which will return a `ResultSet`, from which you will then need to inspect the result of the first row

Something like...

```
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select exists(select 1 from calcul where to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')=to_char("+dates+", 'YYYY-MM') AND idproduit="+codeP+" AND ppa="+PPA+" AND tr="+TR+" AND net="+NET+" AND dateper='"+datePer+"')")) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            boolean exists = rs.getBoolean(1);
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

for example.

Having said that, I'd strongly encourage you to use a `PreparedStatement`, see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

For example...

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select exists(select 1 from calcul where to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')=to_char(?, 'YYYY-MM') AND idproduit=? AND ppa=? AND tr=? AND net=? AND dateper='?')")) {
    stmt.setString(1, dates);
    stmt.setString(2, codeP);
    stmt.setString(3, PPA);
    stmt.setString(4, TR);
    stmt.setString(5, NET);
    stmt.setString(6, datePer);
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            boolean exists = rs.getBoolean(1);
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `true` just means that there is a result, as stated in the javadoc of [`execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()):

> Returns:
>   true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if the first result is an update count or there is no result.

You need to call [`getResultSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet()) to get the actual result.